# Aggreagation and differences between two data frames - Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My data frame looks like below

DF1 :

```
A    B    Value
0   abc   200
xyz  0     300
```

DF2:

```
A    B    Value
abc   0    400
0     xyz    500
```

I need to calculate the difference between the two dataframes for Value(column)
I am using "coalesce" function to get the IDs

ID    Value
abc   200
xyz    300

similarly for DF2

Need help in :
1) changing/adding a column name which could contain results from coalesce function
Tried below code: doesnt work, it gives me null values

```
df1.select(coalesce(df1["A"],df1["B"]).alias("ID"))
```

Also I want to display as 
ID , Value
abc  200

2) How do I join these two dataframes based on ID and then subtract values in the same query and display both ID as ID and difference as new column called as "diff"

```
Expected OUtput:

ID    Value
abc   200
xyz   200
```

Comment: can you share the expected output dataframe

Comment: df1 = df1.withColumn("ID", coalesce(df1["A"],df1["B"])) and read the doc for the join https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join

Comment: Added expected output